# Map in Java and Javascript

Tags: java, javascript, iterator, hashmap, liferay

I need to pass a `HashMap` object from backing bean (JSF) to JavaScript and iterate it.

When I get the object in javascript, I checked it is not null but can't iterate.

Is there any kind of `Map` that can be used in my scenario? or, How can I convert my `HashMap` object to normal JavaScript object that can be iterated with jQuery?

Comment: If it's not `null`, then what is it?

Comment: I dont know, I use if statement to check whether it is null or not, but it really not null ^^z

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert objects to [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) using free library like [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).
Jquery will be able to recive it via [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) and iterate it using [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: I use HttpServletResponse and write jSon String. But ^^z i dont know how to get that object in JavaScript

Comment: String jSon = ClassCommon.convertToJson(componentSyncIds);
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    PortletResponse portletResponse = (PortletResponse) externalContext.getResponse();
    HttpServletResponse response = PortalUtil.getHttpServletResponse(portletResponse);
    response.setContentType("application/json");
          response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
          response.getWriter().write(jSon);

Answer (score 0):

Give [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) a try. You can convert some Java objects to JSON and read this with JavaScript. You have to find a way to communicate then, maybe [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not using JSON, you could put your map values into a hidden element. [Definition lists](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp) is a natural match for maps:

```
<dl>
  <dt>Coffee</dt>
  <dd>- black hot drink</dd>
  <dt>Milk</dt>
  <dd>- white cold drink</dd>
</dl>
```

you could also use a table.

Here is a [nice overview](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2009/05/javajspjsf-and-javascript.html) from BalusC with different techniques for JSF-to-JS communication: